# The biggest value in array and check if all elements in array have equal values. (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on a project. The user inputs a value(n) and that value is multiplied by 2. Then the user inputs the exact same times a new number (n*2). So I have to figure out if every couple of numbers are equal and if not to print the biggest difference between one of the couples. In order to do that I need Biggest value in an array and somehow to check if all elements in an array are equal. I'm new to C# and I don't know much about arrays.(btw sorry about the use of language, I'm foreigner)
I came up with this code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EqualPairs
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int sum = 0;
        int diff = 0;
        int[] sumAll = new int[n];
        int[] differ = new int[n];
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            diff = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
            {
                int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                sum = sum + number;
                diff = Math.Abs(diff - number);
            }
            sumAll[i - 1] = sum;
            differ[i - 1] = diff;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do with your program, but to answer your questions:

Find max value in an array:

```
int maxValue = yourArray.Max();
```

Check if all values in your array are equal (using System.Linq):

```
int first = yourArray.First();
bool allElementsEqual = yourArray.All(x => x == first);
```

**Edit based on OP's comment:**

If I were you, I'd create an intermediate array `couplesArray`. Not sure how you're planning to set up your inputs and all that, but I'm assuming `yourArray` has an even number of values. I don't know how you're defining max difference and all that, so perhaps drop some of my Math.Abs() calls:

```
int[] yourArray = { 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, -1};
int[] couplesArray = new int[yourArray.Count() / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < couplesArray.Length; i++)
{
    couplesArray[i] = yourArray[2 * i] + yourArray[2 * i + 1];
}


int first = couplesArray.First();
bool allElementsEqual = couplesArray.All(x => x == first);

int maxDifference = Math.Max(Math.Abs(couplesArray.Max()), Math.Abs(couplesArray.Min()));

string outputString = allElementsEqual ? "Equal" : maxDifference.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(outputString);
```

Comment: sorry, but your `<bool expression> ? true : false` part is very redundant. Just use the return value of the expression ;)

Comment: Why use the ternary operator in the end? Enumerable.All() already returns a boolean.

Comment: @Stefan: you're completely correct, so I edited my post. I'm currently working on some legacy code with way too many conditional operators, so I guess it just got stuck in my head. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: I mean when you input a number (e.g. 3), you have to input twice more numbers (e.g. 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, -1). Now split every two numbers into a couple.
(couple1 = 1 & 2, couple2 = 0 & 3, couple3 = 4 & -1). Now when you sum all numbers in every couple(group) you'll get couple1 = 3, couple2 = 3, couple3 = 3. If all values are equal, print out "Equal". If the values are not equal, print out the biggest difference(e.g. couple1Diff = 1, couple2Diff = 2, couple3Diff = 3) output: 3; I don't know if you can understand it, I'm a foreigner. Sorry.

Comment: VG98: I updated my code. Please let me know if I have misinterpreted anything.

Comment: @C.Helling Thank you.